# path helper issue in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am migrating a application from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1, i am using a path helper like **`student_teacher_path(@student,teacher.id)`**, this used to work in **rails 2.3 even if teacher.id is nil** i mean it did not generate a exception in 2.3.

But with rails 3.1 i am getting a exception like **`ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers", :student_id=>#<Student id:>,nil})`**

How do i handle this in rails 3.1. Is there any better way to this other than using a if else and check if teacher.id is nil and display data accordingly.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet would be making sure that `teacher` is not null.

Comment: but is there a reason in rails 2.3 no exception was generated and rails 3.1 it generates a exception

Comment: It would be helpful to paste the rest of the error message

Comment: hi Kristján, i have modified my question with full error msg